# HTML Newsletter - Links on the same line on iOS

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, newsletter

I am developing a newsletter template and I have a very basic multi-cell footer which renders perfectly in IE/FF and Outlook. But when I read the email from iPhone or iPad the links in the footer menu are displayed on two lines. Can somebody be so kind to help me understand why this happen and how I can obtained the desired result also on iPhone/iPad?

Here is my code (just the portion containing the footer):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
<table id="background-table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;">
<!-- block preamble starts -->
<table class="l-preamble" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td class="has-border-bottom-1" height="16" width="600" style="color: #6f6f6f; border-bottom: 1px solid #6f6f6f;"></td>
</tr>
<!-- element preamble-info ends -->
<!-- element preamble-year starts -->
<tr>
<td width='420'>
<table class="small-font" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; font-size: 12px; color: #b2b2b2 !important; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td class="fabsize" class='is-last' style="letter-spacing: 0; padding-right: 12px; ">
<font style=' color: #b2b2b2;'>
<a href="http://www.test/fab" target="blank" style="line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;color: #b2b2b2;">
Responsibles
</a>
</font>
</td>
<td class="fabsize" class='is-last' style="letter-spacing: 0; padding-right: 12px; padding-left: 12px; border-left: 1px solid #b2b2b2;">
<font style=' color: #b2b2b2;'>
<a href="http://www.test/fab" target="blank" style="line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;color: #b2b2b2;">
Disclaimer
</a>
</font>
</td>
<td class="fabsize" class='is-last' style="letter-spacing: 0; padding-right: 12px; padding-left: 12px; border-left: 1px solid #b2b2b2;">
<font style=' color: #b2b2b2;'>
<a href="http://www.test/fab" target="blank" style="line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;color: #b2b2b2;">
Feedback
</a>
</font>
</td>
<td class="fabsize" class='is-last' style="letter-spacing: 0; padding-right: 12px; padding-left: 12px; border-left: 1px solid #b2b2b2;">
<font style=' color: #b2b2b2;'>
<a href="http://www.test/fab" target="blank" style="line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;color: #b2b2b2;">
RSS feeds
</a>
</font>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td width="180" align="right" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;">
<table class="small-font" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; font-size: 12px; color: #b2b2b2 !important; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td class="is-first" style="color: #6f6f6f;letter-spacing: 0; padding: 0px; border: 0px">
<span style="color: #b2b2b2; line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
&copy; 2013&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;LLLLLVSKI
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because they simply don't fit on one line on ipad/iphone.

Comment: What footers? There are no footers in your code.

Comment: Also, remove the errors from your html and then try again. And there is no good reason, nor has there ever been, for writing `bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="color: #6f6f6f;`

Comment: Hello! Well, I don't get why it doesn't fit in one line. What should I change? The rest of the page is displayed correctly. 

Concerning the errors in mark-up, I am developing for newsletter, so I used a tool to generate the mark-up. As newsletter standard is rather old, bgcolor is still a valid command. It is funny that it uses different values for the color but I assume there is a reason for that.

Comment: @MrLister `bgcolor` is the correct way to declare background colors in html email. `style="color:#6f6f6f;"` is the best way to declare text. Fabbio has it right.

Comment: @John I have never seen an email reader that did interpret the `color` style correctly, but had troubles with the `background-color` style. Similarly, email readers that know about `bgcolor` also know about `<font color...` and then there would be no need for styles.

Comment: @MrLister Email clients are all over the place with their support, so coding for email will always be a bit of a hack job. I know it seems silly, but the combination of the two I mentioned above are the most widely used combination in the html email design industry.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your copyright part goes to the next row is because you are floating (aligning to be precise) two tables next to each other. Your main footer is 420 and your copyright info is 180, and although they are housed in a 600px wide cell, they do not fit, at least on iPhone/iPad.

My first guess is because you haven't declared exact widths on the table cells (Responsibilities, Disclaimer etc...), so it is pushing your 480px table wider.

If you always want them to be the same line though, it is much easier to have one table instead of flirting with side by side ones with align="left".

Take the td cell from the copyright table and put it into the other one. Also, you don't need `<tbody>` tags in email, so remove them also.

Should look something like this:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font style=' color: #b2b2b2;'>
        <a href="http://www.test/fab" target="blank" style="line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;color: #b2b2b2;">Responsibles </a>
      </font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style=' color: #b2b2b2;'>
        <a href="http://www.test/fab" target="blank" style="line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;color: #b2b2b2;">Disclaimer </a>
      </font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style=' color: #b2b2b2;'>
        <a href="http://www.test/fab" target="blank" style="line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;color: #b2b2b2;">Feedback </a>
      </font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style=' color: #b2b2b2;'>
        <a href="http://www.test/fab" target="blank" style="line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;color: #b2b2b2;">RSS feeds </a>
      </font>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font style=' color: #b2b2b2;'>
        <font style="color: #b2b2b2; line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
          &copy; 2013&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;LLLLLVSKI
        </font>
      </font>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ciao John! Thanks a lot for your reply. I did some test and yes, now the links are displayed in the same line but one needs to swipe to see the whole footer. Probably my problem description was not clear enough. In my version what breaks to a new line are the single items on the left side (Responsibles, Disclaimer, Feedback, RSS feeds). But at least the whole footer is visible without swiping.

I created a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/FcqNp/

Comment: @Fabbio can you please send a screenshot of what is breaking - it will help pinpoint the issue.